# C# XML SelectNodes function

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

This is my first post and I have am concerned that some might think I have bothered trying to solve the problem myself, so forgive me if I rant on. I am currently trying to develop a set of functions for importing an xml document and creating a basic object from it.

Currently I have this code looking for all xml files in a directory and displaying the file names in a listbox. Overall there's about 10,000 xml files so it take a while to load.

```
public void CreateLibrary()
{
        List<string> fixtureList = new List<String>();
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows.old\Users\Michael\Desktop\Application_ DEV\XMLData", "*.xml",
                                     SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string dir in dirs)
{
            string fixture = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dir);


            lbxLibrary.Items.Add(fixture);
}
```

What I would like to happen is when the user selects a new listbox item, the url for the file is passed to a GetData function. see below:

selection change event

```
private void lbxLibrary_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
           lblFixtureName.Text = fixture.GetModelName("C:\Windows.old\Users\Michael\Desktop\Application_ DEV\XMLData\\ExampleData.xml");
    }
```

GetModelName function - this is in a different class.

```
        public string GetModelName(string url)
    {
        //Import fixture xml 
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(url);

        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/FixtureModel/");

        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            ModelName = xn["ModelName"].InnerText;
        }

        return ModelName;

    }
```

I current get an 'XmlException was unhandled' error in the GetModelName function.

The exact line I am having issues appears to be where I am passing the directory location in.

```
xml.LoadXml(url);
```

Does anybody have any ideas on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `LoadXml` is used to parse a string containing an XML document.  `Load` is used to parse XML retrieved from a URL.

2) You're not properly escaping characters in the URL, as you will find once you use the right method.  Either double your backslashes or prefix the string with an `@` sign.

Comment: Got this working perfectly now. Had a few other errors to sort out and am still working on a few bits and bobs. This problem has been solved. Cheers for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Load instead of LoadXml:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx

LoadXml accepts string in XML format instead of Url.